# Trying to link data and then using ampscript to display different content blocks

Tags: salesforce-marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm trying to bring in data from another (shared) DE and then using IF statement to show a specific content block depending on the outcome. I have managed to get rid of the errors but no content block is showing. Where am I going wrong?

````
SET @CustomerContactable = Lookup ('ENT.Customerdata', 'CustomerContactable', 'Id', @SubscriberKey)

IF @CustomerContactable == 'True' THEN SET @BodyContent = ContentBlockbyId("127410") ELSE 

SET @BodyContent = ContentBlockbyId("127411") ENDIF]%%```
````

Answer (score 0):

Your code block doesn't display the actual content block. It only "sets" the content block based upon your "LookUp" function, on the data row.
You would need to add `%%=TreatAsContent(@BodyContent)=%%`